# Hibernate: how to map several join tables to Java objects (user's list of books)

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have this database structure. There are users who read books every year and compile lists of books that they've read:

```
users       years        books----booklists
   |           |                      |
   ------------------------------------
               |      
           userlists
```

I've tried to do some mappings myself, but I don't think I'm correct.

```
users:
+-----------+---------+
|    id     |  name   |
+-----------+---------+
```

```
@Entity
public class User  {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  //?
  private List<UserList> booklists = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Each user has a list of the **books** they've read *in a certain year*:

```
books:
+-----------+---------+
|    id     |  title  |
+-----------+---------+
```

```
@Entity
public class Book  {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private int id;
}
```

the lists for every user are inside the **booklists** table:

```
booklists:
+-----+---------+---------+
| id  | list_id | book_id |
+-----+---------+---------+
```

```
@Entity
public class BookList  {
  @Column(name="list_id")
  private int id;

  @JoinTable(
            name = "books",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "list_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "list_id"

            ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "book_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"
            )

    )
    @OneToMany
    private Collection<Book> books;
}
```

finally the booklists and users are united inside **userlists**:

```
years:
+----+------+
| id | year |
+----+------+

userlists:
+-----+---------+---------+---------+
| id  | user_id | list_id | year_id |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+
```

```
@Entity
public class UserList  {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserDao user;

    @JoinTable(
            name = "userlists",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"
            ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "year_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"
            )
    )
    @OneToOne
    private String year;

    //?
    private BookList bookList;
}
```

I'm not sure how to get the `private List<UserList> booklists = new ArrayList<>();` inside `User`. I know that one-to-many could be mapped like this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="list_id")
List<UserList> booklists = new ArrayList<>();
```

But my situation has more tables than any tutorials I've seen.

**EDIT**: It was pointed out to me, that it's ok to get rid of the `userlists` table and place information about `user_id` and `year_id` inside `booklists`. I'm still not entirely sure how to map it properly, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: ID for years? Really? Isn't year uniq number by itself?

Comment: @KenBekov I was thinking of maybe associating some additional program-related information with each year, so decided to make it more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this particular problem is somewhat unique in that, for the tables you have defined, you have a `list_id` but no entity for it. The `list_id` is just a sort of sub key or something that identifies a list. I would question the normalization of the tables as you mentioned in the EDIT above, but first things first.

The essential entities are the `User`, the `Book`, and the `Year` entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User {
   @Id
   private int id;  
   private String name;
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
@Data
public class Book {
   @Id
   private int id;
   private String title;
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "years")
@Data
public class Year {
   @Id
   private int id;
   private int year;
}
```

As you have described it you can create a `ListId`, `Booklist`, and `Userlist` set of relationship tables list so:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class ListId {
    @Column(name="list_id")
    private int listId;     
    @Id
    private int id;
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "booklists")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class Booklist extends ListId {  
    @ManyToOne
    private Book book;
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "userlists")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class Userlist extends ListId {  
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne
    private Year year;
}
```

There are definitely other ways to do this, but none will solve the problem of not having a real `ListId` entity to do JPA relationships on. However, you can use this setup like so:

```
List<Booklist> bls = em.createQuery("select bl from Booklist bl left outer join Userlist ul on ul.listId = bl.listId where ul.user = :user", Booklist.class)
        .setParameter("user", u1)
        .getResultList();
bls.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This requires a somewhat newer version of JPA, perhaps 2.2 level. At least it requires Hibernate 5.1 or greater as the implementation. If you want to add a bidirectional mapping to `User` for this schema, then:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
Set<Userlist> booklists;
```

And use it like so.

```
List<Booklist> bls3 = em.createQuery("select bl from User u left outer join u.booklists ul left outer join Booklist bl on ul.listId = bl.listId where u = :user and ul.year = :year", Booklist.class)
        .setParameter("user", u1)
        .setParameter("year", y1)
        .getResultList();
bls3.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Assuming that you have some leeway in designing the schema the way you want to for the job, then yes, you should change it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "booklists")
@Data
@ToString(exclude = "user")
public class Booklist {     
    @Id
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Book book;      
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;      
    @ManyToOne
    private Year year;
}
```

Using it is much easier and wouldn't require the non-related entities join from JPA 2.2 or an unmapped `ListId` class.

```
List<Booklist> bls2 = em.createQuery("select bl from Booklist bl where bl.user = :user", Booklist.class)
        .setParameter("user", u2)
        .getResultList();
bls2.forEach(System.out::println);
```

You can add a bidirectional mapping to `User`.

```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
   Set<Booklist> booklists;
```

And use it like so:

```
List<Booklist> bls3 = em.createQuery("select bl from User u left outer join u.booklists bl where u = :user and bl.year = :year", Booklist.class)
        .setParameter("user", u1)
        .setParameter("year", y1)
        .getResultList();
bls3.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This later schema gives you the same results as the former. If it wasn't so late I'd try to figure out which of the first 3 levels of normalization your first schema was violating but perhaps that's an exercise best left to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

**Requirements**

Keep track of all `books` read by `users` in particular `years`.
There might be some additional program-related information associated with `year`.

**Data model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
@Data
public class Book {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String isbn;
  private String title;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "years")
@Data
public class Year {

  @Id
  private Integer year;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "book_lists",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "year"}))
@Data
public class BookList {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "year")
  private Year year;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "book_lists_books",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_list_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"))
  private Set<Book> books = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

**DB schema** (PostgreSQL)

```
CREATE TABLE years
(
    year integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (year)
);

CREATE TABLE users
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE books
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    isbn character varying(255),
    title character varying(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE book_lists
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    user_id bigint,
    year integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (year) REFERENCES years (year),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
    UNIQUE (user_id, year)
);

CREATE TABLE book_lists_books
(
    book_list_id bigint NOT NULL,
    book_id bigint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (book_list_id, book_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (book_list_id) REFERENCES book_lists (id)
);
```

**Example**

```
User johnDoe = new User();
johnDoe.setName("John Doe");
em.persist(johnDoe);

Book poeaaBook = new Book();
poeaaBook.setIsbn("007-6092019909");
poeaaBook.setTitle("Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture");
em.persist(poeaaBook);

Book eipBook = new Book();
eipBook.setIsbn("978-0321200686");
eipBook.setTitle("Enterprise Integration Patterns");
em.persist(eipBook);

Year year2019 = new Year();
year2019.setYear(2019);

BookList johnDoe2019BookList = new BookList();
johnDoe2019BookList.setUser(johnDoe);
johnDoe2019BookList.setYear(year2019);
johnDoe2019BookList.getBooks().add(poeaaBook);
johnDoe2019BookList.getBooks().add(eipBook);
em.persist(johnDoe2019BookList);
```

`em.find(BookList.class, johnDoe2019BookList.getId())` returns

```
BookList(id=4, user=User(id=1, name=John Doe), year=Year(year=2019), books=[Book(id=2, isbn=007-6092019909, title=Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture), Book(id=3, isbn=978-0321200686, title=Enterprise Integration Patterns)])
```